# Does having too many subqueries in the from clause slow down the query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having to create subqueries in the from clause just to write cleaner code but in return does having too many subqueries slow down the query.

for example:

```
select id,
  name,
  annual_income * 0.10 AS tax
from (
  select id,
    name,
    annual_income
  from (
     select id,
       first_name || ' ' || last_name AS name
       income * 12 AS annual_income
  )
);
```

the above is just a made up example

Comment: General comment: you can often replace subqueries with more efficient JOINs, especially if you have good indexes.

Comment: If the subqueries are simple the Oracle planner will probably be able to inline them, so optimization will be possible. If the subqueries become too complex, then Oracle will have trouble optimizing them. I would recommend writing the query the way you prefer (cleaner way) and get the execution plan. If it's bad, then you can start rewriting the query for performance.

Comment: @TheImpaler there are simple but will become more complex as I need to have 48 group by joins all returning a scalar value on top of 3 layers of subqueries.

Comment: Generally code readability is more improved with CTE (`with` clause) than inline subquery in the `from`, because you may write some piece of code in one place and reuse it as a general table in other parts (with no need to count brackets and create deep indentation). But if it is accessed more than once or has rownum pseudo-column, optimizer may materialize it (as described in the MT0's answer), which may significantly affect performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TL;DR] It depends on the queries you are using in the sub-queries.

---

In your case:

```sql
select id,
       name,
       annual_income * 0.10 AS tax
from   (
  select id,
         name,
         annual_income
  from   (
    select id,
           first_name || ' ' || last_name AS name
           income * 12 AS annual_income
    from   table_name
  )
);
```

Will get rewritten by the SQL engine to:

```sql
select id,
       first_name || ' ' || last_name AS name
       income * 1.2 AS tax
from   table_name;
```

There will be no difference in performance between the two queries and if it is easier for you to understand and/or maintain the query in its expanded form then you should use that format and not worry about the nested sub-queries.

---

However, there are some cases when sub-queries can affect performance. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72985632/1509264) was a particularly complex issue where the sub-query factoring clause was being materialized by the inclusion of the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column and that forced the SQL engine to execute in a particular order and prevented if from rewriting the query into a more optimal form and prevented it from using an index which made the query very slow.